# Error exporting an string

Tags: android, string, android-intent, bundle

I've made an app that connects to SQL database and they returns me the entries from database table.

What I have done is: In the app i can see the entries what are in database table. What I want is: When I select the entry in the app, automatically it opens another window and displays the entry what I have selected.

But now it gives me an error (Sorry! The application net Ben (process net.ben) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again) and the application is closing. I think that it is something with convert Arraylist string to bundle string.

This is my code:

```
public class SeleccionarTipoIncidencia extends Activity {
private ArrayList<String> datos;
public String PRUEBA;
//private ArrayList<String> datosCod;

//public NaviverdeSQLiteHelper usdbh;
protected EspaisVerdsApplication app;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tipoincidencia);
    datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    //datosCod = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        NotesCenter messageCenter = new NotesCenterImpl();

        List<TipoIncidencia> tipoincidencia = messageCenter.getTipoIncidencia();

        for (TipoIncidencia e : tipoincidencia) {
            //datosCod.add("1");
            datos.add(e.id);

        }   
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        //  showMessage(ex);
            Log.v("blah", ex.getMessage());
        }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);     

    final TextView lblMensaje = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MensajeTipoIncidencia);       
    final GridView grdOpciones = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.GridTipoIncidencia);
    Log.i("YourApp", "Argh Works?");
    grdOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {        
            lblMensaje.setText("Incidencia Seleccionada: " + datos.get(position));

                Intent intentTipIni = new Intent(SeleccionarTipoIncidencia.this, FrmIncidencias.class);
                            //Creamos la información a pasar entre actividades
                            Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
                            b.putString("TIPOINCIDENCIA", lblMensaje.getText().toString());

                            //Añadimos la información al intent
                            intentTipIni.putExtras(b);

                            //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
                            startActivity(intentTipIni);
                            Log.i("YourApp", "Bueno7"); 
                            finish();
        }
    });

    grdOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
}
protected PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frmincidencias);

    TextView txtSaludo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtTipoIncidenciaSeleccionado);

    //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    //Construimos el mensaje a mostrar
    txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + bundle.getString("TIPOINCIDENCIA"));
```

I get an error at the last line.

Comment: Please mention what exact errors are you receiving? We are not going to copy your code and test the entire application for you.

Comment: post the [logcat](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+how+to+get+logcat) of your app, not the message in dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure how `putExtras` works, but I trust `putExtra(String, String)` to work as expected (I used it several times) so instead of creating a `Bundle` I would do the following:

```
Intent intentTipIni = new Intent(SeleccionarTipoIncidencia.this, FrmIncidencias.class);
intentTipIni.putExtra("TIPOINCIDENCIA", lblMensaje.getText().toString());
startActivity(intentTipIni);
```

### Edit

Also, it could be

```
TextView txtSaludo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtTipoIncidenciaSeleccionado);
```

that is `null`. Can you make sure it is not `null`?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Now how i get that putExtra in the class that i want to show the data?

Comment: using either getIntent().getExtras().getString("") or getIntent().getExtraString()

Comment: Yes, it is null, because my app works in that way:
[FIRST SCREEN] --> [SECOND SCREEN] --> [THIRD SCREEN]

On the first screen there is only button what opens the Second Screen. 
On the second screen appears data what i will select on the third screen
On the third screen i select the data.

I think that it gives me an error because when I open for the first time the second screen the string is null.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking that `startActivity(Intent i)` actually succeeds? If not it may not bind the `Intent` to your class and then you may not have a `Bundle` assigned. Hence you get a `NullPointerException`, or perhaps not the right `Bundle` in which case, your `String` "T...." is not a valid key, so throws an error. Check that.